# Two series with $a_n/b_n\to 1$ converges simultaneously?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For two series $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$, if $a_n/b_n\to 1, (n\to\infty)$, can we assert that if $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\sum b_n$ converges; if $\sum a_n$ diverges, then $\sum b_n$ diverges.

I think it is wrong, but could not find a counterexample..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement is false. Take, for instance,
$$a_n=(-1)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
which converges because it is an alternating series decreasing in absolute value, and
$$b_n=(-1)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}n$$
which does not converge since $b_n-a_n=\frac{1}n$ meaning that the difference between their $n^{th}$ partial sums is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}i$, which diverges, meaning that, given that the partial sums of $a_n$ converge, those of $b_n$ must diverge. However $$\frac{b_n}{a_n}=1+\frac{\frac{1}n}{(-1)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}=1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$$
which goes to $1$ for large $n$.

The idea here is that alternating series can converge arbitrarily slowly. A more general construction would be to leverage this fact by choosing a sequence $k_n$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|k_n|=0$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}k_n$ diverges. Then, choose some decreasing sequence of positive values $c_n$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|k_n|}{c_n}=0$. Then, setting $a_n=(-1)^nc_n$ and $b_n=a_n+k_n$ yields a counterexample.

Comment: For series with non-positive terms, I think that you need to work a little harder than that.

Comment: @Martin Yep, I noticed this too and was editing when you commented; I fixed it, I think.

Comment: Yes. But to really have an argument I think that you need to consider splitting the series in the series of positive terms and the series of negative terms. Annoying to write and useless in the complex case, where you would thing the same result should hold.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for pointing out that it doesn't hold in the complex case and that my proof was suspicious looking - it led me to show that the statement *is* false (except when restricted to non-negative sequences).

Comment: nice example. I tried for a minute along that line but I didn't think of using a slow-converging term. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

If they both are positive then $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \to 1 \implies \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ is bounded by $M$(say), then $$a_n<M\cdot b_n$$ Now from here we can say if $\sum b_n$ converges then $\sum a_n$ converges and if $\sum a_n$ diverges then $\sum b_n$ diverges too.